# Ruby 1.9.2 + FreeBSD

Tags: ruby, freebsd

Does anybody use Ruby 1.9.* in FreeBSD 7.* ? How does you solve problem "NotImplementedError: fork() function is unimplemented on this machine" ? ( http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/2097#change-5823 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to FreeBSD 7.4 or greater. Worked for me.